# Calculating request per second using InfluxDB on Grafana

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I use telegraf plugin nginx to read Nginx's basic status information (ngx_http_stub_status_module)

This is my query

[image: request per second query]

raw sql:

```
SELECT derivative(mean("requests"), 1s) FROM "nginx" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval) fill(null)
```

This is my data

```
time            accepts active  handled host    port    reading requests    server      waitingwriting
1464921070000000000 7   1   7   hysm    80  0   17      localhost   0   1
1464921080000000000 8   1   8   hysm    80  0   19      localhost   0   1
1464921090000000000 8   1   8   hysm    80  0   20      localhost   0   1
1464921100000000000 8   1   8   hysm    80  0   21      localhost   0   1
```

but requestPerSecond is 0.083, what is wrong with my query?

[image: request per second graph]

Comment: What do you expect it to be? My first inclination is that you're taking the average and then taking the derivative of that which should skew things a bit because your average will change in relation to your `group by time($interval)`.

Comment: Have you tried setting the unit on the derivative to be equal to the `GROUP BY time()` interval? (usually defaults to 10s in Grafana)

Comment: @MichaelDesa, I would like to know whether the result(requestPerSecond) is right

Comment: What does `requests` represent? Is it just a counter? If it is then you'll want to run `derivative(max(requests))` that should give you something more accurate than `mean`.

Comment: @MichaelDesa, just a counter, thanks

Comment: Hey @jk2K , can you please tell me the setup by which you are able to get this nginx info on influxdb. How have you connected your stub_module to influxdb ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you're dealing with a a counter, the query you're going to want is

```
SELECT derivative(max(requests))
FROM "nginx"
WHERE $timeFilter
GROUP BY time($interval)
```

Comment: What if you have to derive the number of requests using `count`?