# How to measure throughput with dynamic interval in Grafana

Tags: monitoring, grafana, influxdb

We are measuring throughput using Grafana and Influx. Of course, we would like to measure throughput in terms how many requests, approximately,  happens **every single second** (rps).
The typical request is:

`SELECT sum("count") / 10 FROM "http_requests" GROUP BY time(10s)`

But we are loosing possibility to use astonishing dynamic `$__interval` that very useful when graph scope is large, like a day of week. When we are changing interval we should change **divider** into `SELECT` expression.

`SELECT sum("count") / $__interval FROM "http_requests" GROUP BY time($__interval)`
But this approach does not work, because of empty result returns.

How to create request using dynamic `$__interval` for throughput measuring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get no results is that `$__interval` is not a number but a string such as `10s`, `1m`, etc. that is understood by influxdb as a time range. So it is not possible to use it the way you are trying.

However, what you want to calculate is the `mean` which is available as a function in InfluxQL. The way to get the behavior that you want is with something like this.

`SELECT mean("count") FROM "http_requests" GROUP BY time($__interval)`

EDIT: On a second thought that is not quite what you want.
You'd probably need to use `derivative`. I'll come back to you on that one later.

Edit2: Do you think this answers the question that you have [Calculating request per second using InfluxDB on Grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631018/calculating-request-per-second-using-influxdb-on-grafana)

Edit3: Third edit's a charm.
We use your starting query and wrap it in another one as such:
`SELECT sum("rps") from (SELECT sum("count") / 10 as rps FROM "http_requests" GROUP BY time(10s)) GROUP BY time($__interval)`

Comment: I must be tired already ... even the third edit is inadequate

Comment: Just to be clear, If we have cumulative sum of something like logins count since Anno Domini, we can use `derivative` function, it calculates the difference for some period of time and eventually, it will be rps.
But if our data is not cumulative, just how many things happens in 10 seconds, we have to use subquery.